# GreenFunction of the Klein-Gordon equation

Tags: differential-equations

Although the [Green's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function) of the [Klein-Gordon equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein%E2%80%93Gordon_equation) is given (precomputed as an example) on the [`DiracDelta`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiracDelta.html) and [`HeavisideTheta`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HeavisideTheta.html) functions documentation pages, Mathematica 11.3 is itself incapable of calculating it with its own [`GreenFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GreenFunction.html).

Can somebody confirm this?

This seems odd, since all Green's functions for other common equations are present and, presumably, hard coded.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Please post your code that highlights the problem that you are having.